# Constantly updated clock in zsh prompt without any drawback?

Tags: time, zsh, prompt

I use the following in my zshrc file:

```
RPROMPT="%{$fg_bold[blue]%}%n@%M, %D %T%{$reset_color%}"
TMOUT=1
TRAPALRM() { zle reset-prompt }
```

It works fine, until I use the completion menu:

```
zmodload -i zsh/complist
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
```

Now, the items in the menu become invisible whenever the prompt refreshes (because of the zle reset-prompt). If that wasn't enough, I also get segfaults when navigating the menu…

So, is there a way to update the time in my prompt without breaking anything?
Thank you.

Comment: Wondering whether you have reported the segfaults to zsh mailing list.

Comment: I haven't, though I talked about it in the IRC channel and they seemed to think it was normal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zsh menu completion causes problems after zle reset-prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526175/zsh-menu-completion-causes-problems-after-zle-reset-prompt)

Comment: @Drasill, my question is older than theirs.

Comment: @sam113101 Indeed, sorry. I answered the other one, then stumbled upon yours - the duplicate flag was in no way intended to be negative.