# widgets can only be called when ZLE is active

Tags: widget, zsh, completion, zsh-zle, fzf

I have been dealing with this problem for almost a month now, and I feel frustrated, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to write a widget for my `takenote` command. The purpose of the widget is to feed all the markdown files in `~/notes` folder into `fzf` so that the user can select one of them and starts editing it.
After the user types `takenote` and presses `<tab>` I expect the widget to run.

Here is the `_takenote.zsh` widget definition:

```zsh
#compdef takenote
local file=$( find -L "$HOME/notes/" -print 2> /dev/null | fzf-tmux +m )
zle reset-prompt
compadd $file
return 1
```

Unfortunately, the above code doesn't work because of `zle reset-prompt`, if I remove it then the result would be like this:

[image: before selection]

And after selecting the file it would turn into:

[image: After selecting the file]

Which as you see will corrupt the prompt and the command itself.
It appears to me that what I need to do is do a `zle reset-prompt`
before calling `compadd` but this can only work when I bind the function to a key otherwise, I will get the following error:

widgets can only be called when ZLE is active

Comment: any luck so far? I would use the solution if you managed.

Comment: No, sorry! It has been a long time and I found no solution. Still I really would like to know the answer. 
Maybe you could upvote the question?

Comment: @animaacija, I tried giving it a shot, but seems like it would require a lot more effort. I can give you a pointer that may help out. This was done for `vim` and you may be able to adapt it to yours. See https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/227

Comment: @ExistMe, third bounty in a row :-). Did you get a chance to look at the link I posted

Comment: @tarun-lalwani thanks, I spent a day on the link you've suggested with no success :) How complicated it can be, I feel that I know nothing about `zle` and it's states. I would say this is mainly a  `zle widget` question rather than `fzf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After two days, I finally managed to find a hint on how to achieve it thanks to the excellent fzf-tab-completion project:

https://github.com/lincheney/fzf-tab-completion/blob/c91959d81320935ae88c090fedde8dcf1ca70a6f/zsh/fzf-zsh-completion.sh#L120

So actually, all that you need to do is:

```bash
#compdef takenote
local file=$( find -L "$HOME/notes/" -print 2> /dev/null | fzf-tmux +m )
compadd $file
    
TRAPEXIT() {
   zle reset-prompt
}
return 0
```

And it finally works. Cheers!

Comment: Great! You finally found the correct answer after 4 years :) Thank you very much for sharing and mentioning the source.

Cheers!

Comment: I only posted since 2 years ago you commented that you are still interested in a better solution ;) also yes it did take a while ;)

Answer (score 6):

I finally found a workaround for the issue. Although I am not satisfied with the strategy since it is not self contained in the widget itself, but it works. The solution involves trapping `fzf-completion` after it is invoked and calling `zle reset-prompt`.

For registering the trap add the following snippet to your `.zshrc` file (see [Zsh menu completion causes problems after zle reset-prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526175/zsh-menu-completion-causes-problems-after-zle-reset-prompt)
):

```zsh
TMOUT=1
TRAPALRM() {
   if [[ "$WIDGET" =~ ^(complete-word|fzf-completion)$ ]]; then
      # limit the reset-prompt functionality to the `takenote` script
      if [[ "$LBUFFER" == "takenote "* ]]; then
         zle reset-prompt
      fi
   fi
}
```

---

The `_takenote` widget:

```zsh
#compdef takenote
local file=$( find -L "$HOME/notes/" -print 2> /dev/null | fzf-tmux +m )
compadd $file
return 0
```

p.s: I would still love to move the trap inside the widget, and avoid registering it in the init script (`.zshrc`)

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error when trying to use `bindkey` for a widget to use vim to open the `fzf` selected file. Turns out I have to open the file in `function1` and then have a `function2` calling function1 and then `reset-prompt` to avoid this `widgets can only be called when ZLE is active` error. Like you said, it is really **frustrating** and took me almost a day to figure out!

Example code:

```sh
## use rg to get file list
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='rg --files --hidden'

## file open (function1)
__my-fo() (
  setopt localoptions pipefail no_aliases 2> /dev/null
  local file=$(eval "${FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND}" | FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--height ${FZF_TMUX_HEIGHT:-40%} --reverse $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS --preview 'bat --color=always --line-range :500 {}'" $(__fzfcmd) -m "$@" | while read item; do
    echo -n "${(q)item}"
  done)
  local ret=$?
  if [[ -n $file ]]; then
    $EDITOR $file
  fi
  return $ret
)

## define zsh widget(function2)
__my-fo-widget(){
  __my-fo
  local ret=$?
  zle reset-prompt
  return $ret
}

zle -N __my-fo-widget
bindkey ^p __my-fo-widget
```

Comment: This question is quite old now and I am still interested in a better solution. As far as I remember when binding to a key combination using `bindkey` a `zle reset-prompt` was enough for doing the job. The real pain is when you want to have it with the tab completion. I couldn't find any alternative than the `TRAPALRM` method.